# Percolating/Busy Music in Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-connect

how can we play busy processing music in Amazon connect for back end transactions?

in our contact flow, we are calling a node javascript lambda which in-turn calls one of our rest service and get the results and responds to lambda call, when the call is returned the connect call resumes, during this time we hear a dead silence of 4 to 7 seconds, we need to play a busy processing music during this time, need help in designing this.

Comment: Please provide your code showing your attempts so far.

Comment: Hi Anteino, we implemented a different solutions for this issue, we call a lambda which will insert the data to dynamo db and return from first lambda, and call an another lambda to go and fetch the data from the dynamo db, but in between the first lambda call and second lambda call, we are playing some music like 2 to 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Amazon Connect doesn't have the functionality to implement your use case. I have tried even with lex, no success so far. We have to wait for Amazon Connect to provide a new feature for the same.

Comment: thanks @Sanjay, i have used some other way to implement this  like forcing the caller to hear a music so that in the background i can finish up my rest calls.